# How to shrink the selected are on illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, logo

well this question is both simple and complicated to explain.

I have a band logo with a C letter of a font and then i have effects on the side and if i select the entire logo it gives me a huge box of selected material and most of it doest have nothing, thats because of the font, is there a way to shrink that just to the area that have material?

I ask this because i save the logo and it is saving Blank area!

[image]

Hope you guys can help me, im not a pro on illustrator!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a logo, select and convert your font via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. This will make the text non-editable, but will remove the surrounding box that goes outside your artboard (the red frame).

Answer (score 0):

Select the logo (C) Layers you want to to reduce/Shrink + Ctrl C > Open New file or create new layer> Paste it there (Ctrl F) > Remove the unwanted layers black backrgound (if you work on the original)

If You just want to scale it proportionally, use scale tool. Select the target layers then look for scale tool a pop up will appear check preview to see the adjustment.

[image]